# Ruby on Rails - Activeadmin, different validation with the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activeadmin

I did register the same Model twice with activeadmin :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Media, as: 'Picture' do
end
ActiveAdmin.register Media, as: 'Video' do
end
```

But I want to have a different validation based on the type. I want this for the video:
models/video.rb

```
validate :validate_video_count
def validate_video_count
    errors.add(:error, "Require minimum 1 video") if self.videos.size < 1
end
```

And this for the picture :
models/picture.rb

```
validate :validate_picture_count
def validate_picture_count
    errors.add(:error, "Require minimum 1 picture") if self.pictures.size < 1
end
```

Comment: I didn't work with ActiveAdmin but aren't you adding the validations inside the rails model? If you do that a simple concern might be enough :) I can help if that's the case.

Comment: Who is `self` on these lines: `self.pictures.size` and `self.videos.size` ?

Comment: Its attribute from the model

Comment: @radubogdan yes, this is inside the rails model. I did specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the reason you don't do the simpler

```
ActiveAdmin.register Picture do
end
ActiveAdmin.register Media do
end
```

This would fix your issue, I think.

If you *must* register the superclass, unfortunately because of a bug in the inherited_resources gem on which activeadmin depends, you need to force the instantiation of the right subclass, like this:

```
controller do
  def create
    klass = Picture # or Video or another subclass
    set_resource_ivar(klass.new(permitted_params["media"]))

    super
  end

  def update
    # similar pattern here to #create
  end
end
```